# LDAP SSO - User not redirecting to user/login/sso to login the visitor

Tags: authentication-authorization

I have implemented LDAP - Single Sign On (SSO) on my Drupal project. All the settings (testing, connecting with server) is working perfectly fine.

The problem is that when I visit my site, the site doesn't authenticate the user.

Upon testing every option regressively, I realized that my site is not redirecting to **http://www.theurl.com/user/login/sso**, which authenticates and sign in the visitor.

When I manually went to **http://www.theurl.com/user/login/sso**, the site authenticated and logged in the user perfectly.

Is there anything I can do to mitigate it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a rule to redirect them to the /user/login/sso. You can make a rule, if user has not logged in auto send them to /user/login/sso. If the user is already logged in send them to the home page.